# When was the Cycles renderer introduced?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am wondering when did the Cycles renderer introduced to Blender, 2010 or 2011? And how stable is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was in 2011 (Summer).
Today, it's just more stable (6 years, it's pretty long), and more complete.